# Как реализовать подобную смену картинок при помощи ползунка

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть задача реализовать подобный слайдер, меняющий картинку при перемещении ползунка вправо или влево. Как это можно сделать? Возможно надо как-то использовать css свойство clip. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: [How to create a “Before & After” image slider with CSS and JS](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-create-a-before-after-image-slider-with-css-and-js-a609d9ba77bf)